# How to write a global variable's seperation spec using verifiable c

Tags: verifiable-c

The following is an example code in C.

```
unsigned int  COUNTER;
unsigned int  get_counter(void) {
    COUNTER ++;
    return COUNTER;
}
```

I wrote its founctional spec using verifiable c (vst), but at the end of the verification I encounter an error "typecheck_error (deref_byvalue tint)". Could any body tell me how to write a correct founc spec of the above c founction?
The point is how to write a global variable's SEP().

(**here is the incorrect one, please correct me**)

```
Definition get_counter_spec :=
 DECLARE _get_counter
  WITH v : Z, counter:val
  PRE []
        PROP  () 
        LOCAL (gvar _COUNTER counter)
        SEP   (data_at Ews tint (Vint (Int.repr v)) counter)
  POST [ tint ]
        PROP () 
        LOCAL(temp ret_temp (Vint (Int.repr (v+1))))
        SEP   (data_at Ews tint (Vint (Int.repr (v+1))) counter).
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bug:   in the C program, COUNTER is declared "unsigned int", but in your get_counter_spec, you use "tint" instead of "tuint".  With that change, the proof goes through right away:  start function; do 4 forward.

Our bug:  The error message you get (in VST 2.0) is quite useless!  I will add an issue-report to improve the error reporting in this kind of case.

Comment: (don't forget to use the   -normalize    option to clightgen)

Comment: This issue is now fixed in the VST master branch, commit 5385f70:  The error message in such cases is much more informative.